# How can i make Desmos equations only visible, if a variable is less than 0?

Tags: desmos

Say i have some variable `k` that I can change, and an equation. How do I make the equation invisible, if, for example, `k<0` is true?

I tried to append `{k<0}` to the equation, which just made the equation invisible at all values of `k`.

Comment: What do you mean by "invisible" ? Do you mean specifying a *domain of definition* ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I just want an equation to not show up on the graph in some way when `k<0` is true.

Comment: I tried it in desmos on my laptop, with the example $y=kx$ {$k>1$}, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @JeanMarie @ZoeAllen also, the variable `k` is not related to the equation in any way. It is not mentioned in the equation.

Comment: $f\left(x\right)=\left\{x<0:x\right\}$ defines $y=x$ on the domain of definition on $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: @JeanMarie i didn't really understand that

Comment: I tried it with $y=x$ {$k>1$} as well, which also works fine.

Comment: should i just give you the link to my graph and tell what i'm trying to make there?

Comment: no way that actually worked i just didnt try 

Comment: @AugustoVasques ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with curly braces, for example:
$$x^2\left\{x > 0\right\}$$

[Here's an example graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sw1umtvb7z)